# Listing previous logins through sftp

Tags: centos, rhel, logs, sftp

Hello people of the stackexchange,

I am having a little difficulty trying to find a location of a particular log file which i'm hoping someone on here could help me with.

What i am trying to do is list the login dates/times for a particular user on our sftp server. 
From researching online i have so far come up

`cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "username"` 
which has listed some of the logins but not as far back as i am looking for.

I have also tried

`last -n 1000 | grep "username"` 
but unfortunately this only seems to work for ssh access to the server rather than sftp (as far as i am aware)

Can anyone think of any other methods of listing the logins from a particular user of an sftp user?

many thanks in advance, daark.
N.B. the user is chrooted to their own home directory if that helps in any way.

**Edit:**
I didn't notice some of the archive files in the first instance, these gave me up to one month worth of logins which is better. New question: By default how long does CentOs hold onto the archived auth logs? If it is more than one month where do the older archives move to? 
I have checked the logrotate.conf and there is no mention of `/var/log/auth.log` so i'm assuming it is using default values.

**Edit:Edit**
I think I may have found the answer I was looking for but posting this anyway just in case it is of any use to some one else.

The logrotate script is `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`. By default these rotate weekly and store up to 4 weeks worth of logs.

I do not yet have the reputation to put this as an answer but if an admin see's this please feel free to close it.

Best wishes ~ daark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS 6, `/var/log/secure` contains output from sshd, which launches the sftp subserver.  By default, you will see messages similar to the following, but not much more:

```
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sshd[1234]: Accepted password for user from 1.2.3.4 port 12345 ssh2
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sshd[1234]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Feb 25 12:34:57 server sshd[1234]: subsystem request for sftp
```

If you want to have more visibility into sftp actions, like which files have been transferred, modify the following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

to be

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -f AUTHPRIV -l INFO
```

and then restart sshd:

```
# service sshd restart
```

Then you will have the default logs plus logs like the following:

```
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sftp-server[1234]: session opened for local user user from 1.2.3.4
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sftp-server[1234]: opendir "/home/user/"
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sftp-server[1234]: closedir "/home/user/"
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sftp-server[1234]: open "/home/user/test" flags READ mode 0666
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sftp-server[1234]: close "/home/user/test" bytes read 1234 written 0
Feb 25 12:34:56 server sftp-server[1234]: session closed for local user user from 1.2.3.4
```